# Concat list of strings in one TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Currently I'm digging myself into WPF and I have the following problem:

My data model (see below) has hierarchical data in 3 layers (a file, a line in a file, the line broken in parts). This I want to display in a TreeView in 2 levels, such that the first level are the files and the second level items are the concatenated strings of the `TextParts` list (formatted differently according to the `IsMatch` property).

So this sample data

```
{ fileA("filename1"): { 
    line1: { part1("text1", false), part2("text2", true), part3("text3", false) }, 
    line2: { part4("text4", false) } 
} }
```

should look like:

- filename1

  - *text1* **text2** *text3*
  - *text4*

(remark: I used bold and italics here instead of the white and yellow background used in my xaml)

I already read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) MS documentation, which gave me a good kick in the whole matter. I'm not sure if this can be done in xaml, or is it possible to generate the template in code-behind somehow?

My data model:

```
class MyModel {
    public ObservableCollection<ResultFile> FileLines { get; }
}
class ResultFile {
    public ObservableCollection<ResultLine> Lines { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class ResultLine {
    public ObservableCollection<ResultTextPart> TextParts { get; }
}
class ResultTextPart {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsMatch { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```xml
<TreeView x:Name="TvSearchResults">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ResultFile}" ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> <!-- ... --> </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ResultLine}">
            <!-- how to display the list of ResultTextPart as single line ? -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ResultTextPart}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Name="tviTextPart" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMatch}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="tviTextPart" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it simple:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ResultLine}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextParts}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

So all you need is actually to use an `ItemsControl` and set the horizontal oriented panel for this container.

Answer (score 2):

This should essentially do what you're asking for. Though there aren't any spaces in between the text, you could add that in with a converter or something. Potentially even removing the whole `ItemsControl` and having a conveter take in the colection and blurt out a string, I just wanted to keep it all in the xaml for you.

```
<TreeView x:Name="TvSearchResults" Width="200" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.FileLines}">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextParts}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMatch}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>    
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```